# How can I access certain columns in a DataFrame based on a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have created a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
data = [[random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1)]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A","B", "C", "D", "E"])
```

The DataFrame looks like this:

```py
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.736739  0.184075  0.727951  0.173798  0.184594
1  0.047031  0.567518  0.103112  0.094116  0.050785
2  0.955045  0.754968  0.235842  0.710304  0.109404
3  0.426293  0.617942  0.304042  0.043034  0.798327
4  0.415225  0.461497  0.263462  0.621364  0.974682
5  0.936775  0.822425  0.073169  0.634906  0.140092
```

What I want to do now is to divide certain columns for example with 2. In this case I'd like to divide column B, D, and E with two. For that I'd like to use a list. Becaus in my real Problem the Indices are Equity-names and the ones I'd like to divide are saved in a list.

That's what I tried:

```py
list = ["B", "D", "E"]
df1 = df[df.columns.intersection(list)] *0.5
print(df1)
```

And the result looks like this:

```py
          B         D         E
0  0.092038  0.086899  0.092297
1  0.283759  0.047058  0.025392
2  0.377484  0.355152  0.054702
3  0.308971  0.021517  0.399164
4  0.230749  0.310682  0.487341
5  0.411212  0.317453  0.070046
```

But what I get is only a DataFrame which only contains the columns from the list. I'd like that my result would contain the new calculated value plus the old values from the columns which weren't in the list.

The result should look like this:

```py
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.736739  0.092038  0.727951  0.086899  0.092297
1  0.047031  0.283759  0.103112  0.047058  0.025392
2  0.955045  0.377484  0.235842  0.355152  0.054702
3  0.426293  0.308971  0.304042  0.021517  0.399164
4  0.415225  0.230749  0.263462  0.310682  0.487341
5  0.936775  0.411212  0.073169  0.317453  0.070046
```

Does anyone know's how I can solve this problem?
Your help is very appreciated.

Best regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[['B','D','E']] = df[['B','D','E']]*0.5
```

@metasomite pointed out in a proposed edit a simplification using `*=`

```
df.loc[:, ['B', 'D', 'E']] *= 0.5,
```

`df` now looks like this:

```
    A           B           C           D           E
0   0.736739    0.092037    0.727951    0.086899    0.092297
1   0.047031    0.283759    0.103112    0.047058    0.025392
2   0.955045    0.377484    0.235842    0.355152    0.054702
3   0.426293    0.308971    0.304042    0.021517    0.399164
4   0.415225    0.230748    0.263462    0.310682    0.487341
5   0.936775    0.411212    0.073169    0.317453    0.070046
```

Comment: `df1` has not yet been created in my scenario. Besides, there's always the option of creating a deep copy and then running this operation given above.

Answer (score 1):

**first create a copy of the original dataframe to not modify this:**

```
df1=df.copy()
```

---

Then You can use [DataFrame.mul](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) or `*`:

```
df1[['B','D','E']] = df1[['B','D','E']].mul(0.5)
```

Also [DataFrame.div](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) or `/`

```
df1[['B','D','E']] = df1[['B','D','E']].div(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use assign function like below

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
data = [[random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1)]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A","B", "C", "D", "E"])

lst = ["B", "D", "E"]

df.assign(**{col:df[col]*0.5 for col in lst})
```

Comment: Use assgin + loop is not necessary for it

Comment: I thought this was a clever way to answer the question. Don't let @ansev get you down

Answer (score 1):

#### `DataFrame.mul(Series)`

```
# Can generalize to different numbers for each column.  
s = pd.Series(0.5, index=['B', 'D', 'E'])

# `reindex` as DataFrame.mul(Series) hasn't implemented `fill_value`
df.mul(s.reindex(df.columns).fillna(1))
```

---

```
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.736739  0.092037  0.727951  0.086899  0.092297
1  0.047031  0.283759  0.103112  0.047058  0.025393
2  0.955045  0.377484  0.235842  0.355152  0.054702
3  0.426293  0.308971  0.304042  0.021517  0.399164
4  0.415225  0.230749  0.263462  0.310682  0.487341
5  0.936775  0.411212  0.073169  0.317453  0.070046
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to solve this in a for loop, iterating through the list that contain the columns name. You can also use it to add them with a new name (Method 2):

```
data = [[random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1)]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A","B", "C", "D", "E"])
cols = ["B","D","E"]
print(df)
for i in cols:
    df[i] = df[i] * 0.5
print(df)
```

Original dataframe (first print):

```
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.245053  0.265646  0.379884  0.125120  0.244205
1  0.900575  0.340778  0.470371  0.201992  0.316867
2  0.286503  0.524801  0.904360  0.214806  0.841444
3  0.535986  0.345602  0.863335  0.607875  0.493185
4  0.950249  0.462833  0.419088  0.948236  0.476547
5  0.162888  0.672005  0.554368  0.494376  0.913913
```

Second dataframe (second print):

```
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.245053  0.132823  0.379884  0.062560  0.122103
1  0.900575  0.170389  0.470371  0.100996  0.158434
2  0.286503  0.262400  0.904360  0.107403  0.420722
3  0.535986  0.172801  0.863335  0.303937  0.246592
4  0.950249  0.231416  0.419088  0.474118  0.238273
5  0.162888  0.336002  0.554368  0.247188  0.456957
```

### Method 2:

```
for i in cols:
    df["new "+i] = df[i] * 0.5
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          A         B         C         D         E     new B     new D     new E
0  0.735067  0.213327  0.416205  0.235860  0.094208  0.106664  0.117930  0.047104
1  0.150027  0.524437  0.393283  0.783323  0.520855  0.262218  0.391661  0.260428
2  0.146858  0.328530  0.288445  0.101783  0.286224  0.164265  0.050892  0.143112
3  0.512124  0.302685  0.062246  0.152522  0.536951  0.151343  0.076261  0.268476
4  0.358646  0.928946  0.766012  0.808933  0.002960  0.464473  0.404466  0.001480
5  0.735067  0.436962  0.796247  0.499950  0.048898  0.218481  0.249975  0.024449
```

Comment: it is not necessary